# Tableau Parameter filter

Tags: tableau-api

I want to use a Parameter to search stations 'worked' information and want to get this details either by Batch Number or ID.

When i do this it shows me all stations if searched by Batch number but the last one only if searched by ID. How can I get all the values either way?
I have attached a sample workbook

Thank you for your help
[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYUfq.png)

Comment: there is not workbook in link, check and re attach

Answer (score 0):

Create a filter that can accept either a Batch Number or ID.

```
[parameter] = [batch number]
or
[parameter] = [id]
```

Set this in the filter shelf on TRUE.